# Generated javadoc but index.html gone weird

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm using Eclipse and I generated a javadoc with it, but when I open index.htmlm this is all I get:

> Generated Documentation (Untitled) targetPage = "" + window.location.search; if (targetPage != "" && targetPage != "undefined") targetPage = targetPage.substring(1); if (targetPage.indexOf(":") != -1) targetPage = "undefined"; function loadFrames() { if (targetPage != "" && targetPage != "undefined") top.classFrame.location = top.targetPage; }

I tried  to do it from the command line too, but it gives this error about javadoc:

> javadoc -sourcepath *sourcepath* -d *destpath*

How can I generate a javadoc?

Comment: Do you have the javadoc.exe in the jdk package ?

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating javadoc using Eclipse, and JavaDoc command needs to be from JDK witch is determined in PATH so everything works fine.